# AltGr key generate spurious Control_L keyPress events

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am using NX Client for Windows V 3.5.0-9 to login remotely to a Redhat system.

When I press AltGr there is sometimes spurious KeyPressed events for Control_L keyPressed generated. I don not know where these events come from. The generated KeyPressed event for Control_L key makes the keyboard layout go into some mod state since the Control_L key appears to be pressed.

[image: Screenshot from xev output]

I need help to come up with some solution to solve the problem. Are there any more debug techniques that can help me to address where the KeyPress event is generated from? Can I automatically generate the KeyRelease event for Control_L key if that is "pressed"?

**Edit:**
I looked at how Windows reads my AltGr key and it turns out that the keyboard generates two key events.
[image: Screenshot from Windows]